# TTS breaks Android Studio's layout preview renderer

Tags: android, android-layout, text-to-speech, classnotfoundexception, preview

I have a custom layout (extends `LinearLayout`) which implements the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` interface. Everything works fine except when opening an activity which contains this layout in Android Studio's editor.

The render of the preview fails because Android Studio can't find the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` class :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnInitListener
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:189)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:127)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:222)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:177)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClass(RenderClassLoader.java:153)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFile(RenderClassLoader.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFile(ModuleClassLoader.java:380)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFromModule(ModuleClassLoader.java:280)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ModuleClassLoader.java:239)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:176)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:56)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:127)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:222)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:485)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:252)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:220)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've already tried to rebuild, clear the cache, refresh the layout, remove the `implements` of my layout class and replace it with a plain listener, and to put every TTS related code inside a `if (!this.isInEditMode)` block, with no success.

Could you help me ?

Comment: _"I have a custom layout (extends LinearLayout) which implements the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener interface."_ Separate the UI and the "business logic" in your app and don't do weird hacks like this. A `Fragment` or an `Activity` should handle the TextToSpeech. (Or a `Service` or a completely separate class...there are plenty of options.) But not a `View` or a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: This layout is meant to be used as a top-level layout for all of the application's activities. It adds all of the common components around the activity, including a navigation bar (the app is for visually impaired people) and the TTS engine.

Comment: One alternative option would be to have a base Activity containing the common functionality that's not directly related to layouts, such as the TTS code. Each Activity would then inherit from the base Activity and get the shared code and functionality that way. That would at least solve this layout editor problem.

Comment: And then I just have to override the setContentView method to inflate the XML of the children activities in my parent activity's desired container. Would that work ?